# Group Weeks in Columns into Months in Column in a Data Frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I was wondering if there is a possibility to group data which is in weeks into months for simple consolidation.
The data frame looks like:

```
structure(list(c("PCE", "PCE", "PCE", "PCE", "PCE", "PCE"), c("3", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), c("2", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), c("4", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), c("5", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), c("3", 
"0", "2", "0", "0", "0"), c("3", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), c("2", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), c("8", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), c("9", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), c("6", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), c("5", 
"0", "2", "0", "0", "0"), c("6", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), c("9", 
"4", "1", "0", "0", "0"), c("4", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), c("3", 
"1", "0", "0", "0", "0"), c("2", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0"), c("3", 
"0", "0", "0", "1", "0"), c("3", "0", "0", "0", "2", "0"), c("2", 
"0", "0", "0", "1", "0"), c("2", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0"), c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "2", "1"), c("0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0"), c("0", 
"0", "0", "1", "2", "0"), c("0", "0", "0", "1", "2", "0"), c("2", 
"0", "0", "3", "1", "0"), c("3", "0", "0", "2", "1", "0"), c("3", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), c("3", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), c("3", 
"0", "0", "0", "1", "0"), c("3", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0"), c("3", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), c("3", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), c("3", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), c("3", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0"), c("3", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), c("3", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), c("3", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), c("1", "0", "0", "0", "2", "0"), c("3", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), c("3", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0"), c("3", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), c("1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), c("3", 
"0", "0", "0", "1", "0"), c("3", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0"), c("3", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), c("3", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), c("2", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), c("3", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), c("3", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), c("3", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0"), c("156", 
"5", "5", "8", "24", "1"), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0)), names = c("Calendar year / week", "2022-09-12", "2022-09-19", 
"2022-09-26", "2022-10-03", "2022-10-10", "2022-10-17", "2022-10-24", 
"2022-10-31", "2022-11-07", "2022-11-14", "2022-11-21", "2022-11-28", 
"2022-12-05", "2022-12-12", "2022-12-19", "2022-12-26", "2023-01-02", 
"2023-01-09", "2023-01-16", "2023-01-23", "2023-01-30", "2023-02-06", 
"2023-02-13", "2023-02-20", "2023-02-27", "2023-03-06", "2023-03-13", 
"2023-03-20", "2023-03-27", "2023-04-03", "2023-04-10", "2023-04-17", 
"2023-04-24", "2023-05-01", "2023-05-08", "2023-05-15", "2023-05-22", 
"2023-05-29", "2023-06-05", "2023-06-12", "2023-06-19", "2023-06-26", 
"2023-07-03", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The above mentioned dataframe look like this image below:

[image]

The Excepted Output is this:

[image]

I would like to know how to aggregate the weekly data together into monthly data as well the sum of the value under it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may remove the columns with names that are `NA` (`complete.cases`), then reshape to long with `pivot_longer`, conver the 'week' names to `month` by using `floor_date` (from `lubridate`), and do a group by `sum` on the 'value' and reshape back to wide with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
# remove the columns with NA as column names
df[complete.cases(names(df))] %>% 
  # create a row sequence identifier
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  # reshape to long format by selecting columns other than the 1st and rn
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(1, rn), names_to = 'week') %>%
  # grouped by rn, 1st column and week dates floored to month
  group_by(rn, `Calendar year / week`,  
    month = floor_date(ymd(week), 'month')) %>%
   # get the sum of value
   summarise(value = sum(as.numeric(value), na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  # reshape to wide format
  pivot_wider(names_from = month, values_from = value) %>%
  select(-rn)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 12
  `Calendar year /…` `2022-09-01` `2022-10-01` `2022-11-01` `2022-12-01` `2023-01-01` `2023-02-01` `2023-03-01` `2023-04-01` `2023-05-01`
  <chr>                     <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1 PCE                           9           21           26           18           10            2           12           12           13
2 PCE                           0            0            0            5            0            0            0            0            0
3 PCE                           0            2            2            1            0            0            0            0            0
4 PCE                           0            0            0            0            0            6            2            0            0
5 PCE                           0            0            0            1            7            6            2            1            3
6 PCE                           0            0            0            0            1            0            0            0            0
# … with 2 more variables: `2023-06-01` <dbl>, `2023-07-01` <dbl>
```

Comment: I know this one works quite well, but I am find it a bit difficult to understand this and will definitely don't think I would be able to replicate the same in case of such similar instance in the future. Is there an easier way to do this so that the code can be understood by a beginner.

Comment: @MrPool I hope the description in the update helps

Comment: This was very much helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: Can I ask why have to written the floor_date(ymd(week), 'month') , I dont understand the ymd(week), isn't the normal syntax, floor_date("Date", 'month/day/year'), Is it because the dates are not in date format and is in character and you wanted to parse/convert it through as dates and since the format in which dates are stores are in "YYYY-MM-DD" all you had to do was just parse it through and not specify the format? Looking forward to your input.

Comment: @MrPool the dates as showed are in year-month-day, which is character class, so i used ymd to convert to Date class (where the order matters i.e ymd for year, month, day.  if it is month/day/year, it will be mdy.   With `floor_date`, it expects a Date class as input and the second argument is the unit.  Here it is month

Comment: (value = sum(as.numeric(value), na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop') in this line, does na.rm=TRUE means that yo can drop the column from the data frame after summing it. 
I went through how you transformed the data frame line by line by creating data frame till %>% and executing how the data frame is transformed and I got to say this idea is absolutely flawless. Quite amazing.

Comment: @MrPool yes, in case there are some NA elements, it needs to be removed, or else even a single NA can lead to output as NA. Thanks.  Generally, lot of people posts questions with examples that may not be generic.  So, if we don't consider those, they will come back again saying that it is not working

Comment: Thank you. I one last question, since the date was in YYYY-MM-DD format you used YMD to parse it through. But my date was initially in this format "Week/34 , Week/35" would it be possible to change such a format was well into this output. Because I create another data frame which had the dates respective to Week/34, Week/35 and then joined it and then dropped the rest of the data to get this in the current format which is posted above. Can floor_Date be used in such cases?

Comment: @MrPool that format is not clear.  Is it only week number with no year or day? in that case may be need to paste with a dummy year and week day to parse it

Comment: Yes, Its just week number without year. Alright Thank you.